# Multiple defaults in Hydra from command line

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I have the following folder structure

```
configs
|------- default.yaml
|------- setting_A.yaml
|------- setting_B.yaml
|------- a bunch of folders
```

My `default.yaml` is

```
defaults:
  - agent: default
  # - setting_A
  # - setting_B

other configs from subfolders
```

`setting_A` and `setting_B` define parameters from different configs file in the subfolders. For instance size of network, timeout, etc... For example, in `setting_A` I am doing something simple so I need small networks, short timeout, etc...
I can select which set of defaults to use by uncommenting either `setting_A` or `setting_B` in `default.yaml`. But this is very annoying. Is there a way to pass it via command line?

Something like `python main.py +defaults=setting_A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using is defining a non overridable config.
See [The Defaults List](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/) page for details.

In short, you need to place your configs in a config group to be able to override them.

Refer to the [Configuring experiments](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/) pattern to see a way to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: I ended up reorganizing my configs.